# Wireless only connects to Google

Tags: internet, wireless-networking, connection

I am using a netgear wireless router to connect to create a wireless network.  When connected to the router via an Ethernet cable everything works correctly.

When connecting to the router via wireless only Google can be accessed.  I've done searches via Google using random words to make sure that it is not a cached page, and these all work. However, trying to connect to any non Google domain the page fails to load.

I've accessed the connection with two different laptops, both are running Windows Vista.  The network connection is strong on both, but the issue persists for both.

Edit: I have configured the wireless networks name and password, and connect to that using the credentials I have defined.  I am sure I am not connecting to a neighbors wireless network.

Edit2: Typing in the direct IP address for CNN.com ( http://157.166.255.19 ) would not resolve.

Comment: What about the hints to try an IP address?

Comment: I haven't gotten home from work yet to try the direct IP addresses

Comment: ...welcome back. What about CarlF's traceroute `157.166.255.19`? And as two laptops show the same problem, so it might be some router setting: I guess people may need to know the exact router type? And: any chance your internet provider limits its services based on some MAC address? I doubt the ethernet and wireless will expose different MAC addresses to your provider, but who knows...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Google Toolbar or something like that installed? What it sounds like to me is that there is no DNS server set up on your wireless DHCP, so you can't access any sites, but Google (for some reason) is either cached or in your local hosts or something, so it's getting out to that site.

Try connecting to some site via their IP address: If you can do that, then it's definitely DNS.  (try: http://157.166.255.19/  <--cnn com)

Answer (score 1):

For Susan and anyone else who's having the same problem and stumbled onto this page. I had the same problem with a Belkin router. Connecting to it via cable worked fine but the wireless connection only let me access Google affiliated sites. In my case, I was able to solve it by disabling "WMM mode". Then I could connect to the Internet just fine. I still have no idea what WMM mode does or doesn't do but disabling it was the only thing that worked. Switching wireless channels, changing wireless modes, none of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to 69.59.196.219 (Superuser's IP address).  If that works, you know the problem is DNS.  If not, not.

If it's not DNS, try a traceroute to that IP address.  Where does it fail?

I agree with Anakun that you may not be connecting to your own router.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to open the network properties, select ipv4 properties and have obtain an IP address automatically selected. After doing all the other recommendations and manually entering a DNS address (8.8.8.8) did this work- such a simple button!